# What is wrong with this update query in java?

Tags: java, database, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am trying to make an update query in my managed bean. Here is the code:

```
try {
       PreparedStatement checkDB1 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("update pocket set balance=? where username=?");
       checkDB1.setDouble(1, (double) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("selectedUserBalance")-total); //This returns the desired result
       checkDB1.setString(2, (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("selectedAccountIban")); //Returns the desired result

       checkDB1.executeQuery();                

   } catch (SQLException e) {
       System.err.println("SQLState: " + ((SQLException)e).getSQLState());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " +((SQLException)e).getSQLState());
   }
```

I see that parameters are set correctly, looks like there is an error in my query. It enters the catch block. Also, i don't know how to see the stack trace, e.printStackTrace does not work here how can i see it? Can anyne help?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: @Abu how can i see the error message?

Comment: just use `e` inside sysout `System.out.println(e);` or `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using executeUpdate instead of executeQuery. I have seen strange problem with executeQuery while doing a db update.